# Как сделать половину слайда?

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка, слайдер

подскажите пожалуйста каким образом можно сделать показ половину слайда? Использую slick, но можно дать советы и по другим слайдерам. Спасибо
[image: с]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задать: `variableWidth: true`, + фиксированную ширину карточкам:

```js
$('.slider').slick({
  slidesToShow: 2,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  dots: false,
  arrows: true,
  infinite: true,
  touchMove: true,
  draggable: true,
  //lazyLoad: 'ondemand',
  prevArrow: '<button class="slick-prev"><i class="fas fa-arrow-left"></i></button>',
  nextArrow: '<button class="slick-next"><i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></button>',
  variableWidth: true,
});
```

```css
p {
  width: 200px;
}

.slider {
  position: relative;
}

.slider:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 50%;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(left top, right top, color-stop(0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), color-stop(100%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js"></script>

<div class="slider">
  <div>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Exercitationem laboriosam corporis, totam quam optio pariatur fugit deserunt ullam doloribus mollitia.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Exercitationem laboriosam corporis, totam quam optio pariatur fugit deserunt ullam doloribus mollitia.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Exercitationem laboriosam corporis, totam quam optio pariatur fugit deserunt ullam doloribus mollitia.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Exercitationem laboriosam corporis, totam quam optio pariatur fugit deserunt ullam doloribus mollitia.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```